# How to run your UI again without rerunning your code

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

I have created a script that manages light setups in maya.
You can save the light setup to a text file and create a thumbnail for it. When the function is called to create a thumbnail I want the UI to refresh completely so that the newly saved setup will then show up in the UI. This worked fine by just calling my showUI() function again at the end of the function but now when the function ends the UI refreshes and then disappears after one millisecond.

I have tried to manually delete the window and create a new one which leaves me with an empty window

```
    def createPreviewPic(self, pRenderCam, pSetupName, *args):
        # print "CREATE PREVIEW PIC CALLED (test)"
        arnoldRender(1, 1, True, True, pRenderCam, ' -layer defaultRenderLayer')

        cmds.setAttr("defaultArnoldDriver.ai_translator", "jpeg", type="string")
        # cmds.setAttr("defaultArnoldDriver.pre", "test", type="string")

        arnoldRender(260, 260, True, True, pRenderCam, ' -layer defaultRenderLayer')

        # mel.eval('renderWindowRender redoPreviousRender renderView')
        editor = 'renderView'
        formatManager = createImageFormats.ImageFormats()
        formatManager.pushRenderGlobalsForDesc("JPEG")
        cmds.renderWindowEditor(editor, e=True,
                                writeImage='%s\%s_pp.jpg' % (self.thumbnailsLocation, pSetupName))
        formatManager.popRenderGlobals()

        JehovaWitness().showUI()
```

This is the function and the "JehovaWitness().showUI()" should just rerun my window

Comment: you need to store your class othewise you need to rerun : winJW = JehovaWitness()

Comment: how do I store my class? Can you show me a small example maybe? I'm quite new at this...

Comment: Like in my comment : winui = JehovaWitness, then winui.show()

Comment: Then I get this error message
"unbound method showUI() must be called with JehovaWitness instance as first argument (got nothing instead)"

if I say winUI = JehovaWitness() and then winUI.showUI() it just does the same thing by disappearing after an instant

Comment: @DrWeeny I've also noticed that it works some of the time but most of the times it fails after the third rerun

Comment: are you coding with pyside\pyqt ? what does your showUI ?

Comment: @DrWeeny 

My showUI function looks like this:
`def showUI(self, *args):
        print "UI RUN (test)"
        cmds.showWindow(self.win)`

Comment: This is my class constructor
`def __init__(self, *args):
        # USER INTERFACE SETUP
        # MAKE WINDOW
        self.windowWidth = 820
        self.windowHeight = 500
        self.previewSize = 260
        self.windowID = "winUI"

        if cmds.window(self.windowID, exists=True):  # simple line deletes the previous window
            cmds.deleteUI(self.windowID)
        self.win = cmds.window(self.windowID, height=self.windowHeight, width=self.windowWidth,
                               title="DynaLight", sizeable=False)`